# grunt exec command not working in magento2 - Unable to find local grunt

Tags: magento2, less-css, grunt

Today I am trying to execute `grunt exec:all` and `grunt exec` commands. Unfortunertly it shown me a error. Earlier it was working fine.
Later I had try to install new Magento 2 setup. Still the error is same:

[image: error preview]

I stuck over here.

I tried following with the help of [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html#grunt_commands):

- re-install `nodejs`
- re-install `npm`
- re-isntall `grunt-cli`
- re-install `grunt`

Other tools/commands are working fine for grunt like `grunt less:luma` and at all. Only the issue is into `grunt exec`.

Can anyone suggest me what is going wrong here? in magento 2?

Answer (score 3):

grunt exec is esentially a shorthand for clearing the folders `var/view_preprocessed`, `var/generation`, `var/log/system.log` and `pub/static` and running

```
php bin/magento dev:source-theme:deploy --type=less --locale=en_US --area=frontend --theme=Package/theme
```

So before running grunt commands you need to make sure that your comand line php is the same as the server php and that it has access to the database.

1. Make sure that the user with which you are running grunt has access
   to delete the `var` and `pub/static` folders.
2. Check the permissions on `bin/magento` and make sure it is **`a+x`** (your issue).
3. Make sure you're running grunt from the folder where the
   `Gruntfile.js` is located.

Comment: This is the solution that most often works for me. When i run into this issue, it's because there are files in the `pub/static` folder that need to be removed before grunt can perform it's magic. The same can happen in the `var` folder, but less often this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your cmd/console as administrator then run that commands again.

Answer (score 0):

You've written you've re-installed `grunt` but are you sure it's installed *locally*? If so, it there should be `grunt` folder in `node_modules`. If not, try running `npm install` in the project root directory.

I'm not entirely sure if it's possible to run Grunt tasks without local `grunt` package being present, but this would explain some tasks working fine with `grunt-cli` still complaining about not being able to find local `grunt` for others.